# Cant delete row from sqlite database android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, handler

im trying to delete a row from my sqlite database.

My Handler class:

```
// Deleting single contact
    public void deleteContact(WhiteList contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }

 // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteTitle(int name) 
    {
        try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + "=" + name, null);
        Log.d("workingasdfasdfasdf", "deleted: " + name);
        db.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I tried both but non of them are working.

I call the code: `db.deleteTitle(1); //delete record with the ID of "1"` onClick of an button

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: for FSM sake ... use the same code as in `deleteContact` !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try closing the name with single quotes:

```
db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + "='" + name + "'", null);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! as well as i had to change int to String! Will accept the answer in 7 mins.